# How to change counter in bash to appending different strings to file

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, counter

i need to get information, which users have connected to facebook from my proxy. I have a 2 loops.

```
#i have format og logs, like squid.log.12.10.2017
#with `ls squid.log*` i am working with all squid logs, day by day
for i in `ls squid.log*`; do
    echo "There is log $i, that we need to check"
    #i am getting count of ip addresses, that were on fb.com and i am writing them to ~/temp_cache
    # like this:
    # 25 192.168.110.5
    # 41 192.168.110.2
    # where 192.168.110.5 have connected to fb.com 25 times
    # and 192.168.110.2 have connected to fb.com 41 times
    zgrep fb.com /var/log/$i | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -k 1 >> ~/temp_cache

    #i am getting only list of ip, without count of connections to facebook
    # like this:
    # 192.168.110.5
    # 192.168.110.2
    ip=$(zgrep fb.com /var/log/$i | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -k 1 | awk '{print $2}')
    for y in $ip; do
        echo "Users from $y:"
        # i have system, that we are using for projects, in this system we have log ip-addresses and logins, from these ip addresses
        # like for this ip 192.168.110.5, i am getting name of user duke
        # main result, like this:
        # duke
        # the_rock
        redmine_users=$(tail -n 500000 /usr/share/redmine/log/production.log | grep -A 3 "$y" | grep "Current user" | awk '{print $3}' | head -n 1)

        # i am appending to lines, name of users for these lines
        # in a result it should be like this:
        # 25 192.168.110.5 duke
        # 41 192.168.110.2 the rock
        counter=$((counter+1))
        sed -i "$counter s|$|   $redmine_users |" ~/temp_cache
    done
    # Delimiter for each day of logs
    echo "------------------------------------------------" >> ~/temp_cache
done
```

For the first looking it works. But it works only for one day. If script is going to second log, i mean `squid.log.13.10.2017`, it make something like this:

```
        25 192.168.110.5 duke
        41 192.168.110.2 the rock
        ______________________________ hogan
        33 192.168.110.1
```

But i want to do this:

```
        25 192.168.110.5 duke
        41 192.168.110.2 the rock
        ______________________________ 
        33 192.168.110.1 hogan
```

I tried to run script manually for one day, with existsing line `______________________________` and with changing

```
        counter=$((counter+1))
        sed -i "$counter s|$|   $redmine_users |" ~/temp_cache
```

to

```
        counter=1
        counter=$((counter+1))
        sed -i "$counter s|$|   $redmine_users |" ~/temp_cache
```

But in a result i have:

```
        ______________________________
        25 192.168.110.5 duke the rock
        41 192.168.110.2
```

How to do, what i want, at least:

```
        ______________________________
        25 192.168.110.5 duke 
        41 192.168.110.2 the rock
```

How to change counter in this construction:

```
        counter=$((counter+1))
        sed -i "$counter s|$|   $redmine_users |" ~/temp_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get it so the name is on the same line as the count and ip?

Assuming this is correct, you simply need to increase your counter after adding the ---- as well as where it currently is.

I do have multiple other issues with the code but I think this answers the main question.  Let me know if I have missed the mark?

Answer (score 0):

i have found. the counter should be in first loop. thanks for attention